# Rails ActiveRecord: pretty errors when deleting dependent entities with foreign keys constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, error-handling

I have in Rails application several tables with foreign keys constraints. For example, every **order** belongs to a customer. There's a **costumer_id** column on the **orders** table.

When I delete a costumer with a placed order, because of database constraints, MySQL returns the error:

> Mysql::Error: Cannot delete or update
>   a parent row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`orders`, CONSTRAINT
>   `orders_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers`
>   (`id`))

And the ugly error pops up on the screen, with all stacktrace and those stuff
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in DevicesController#destroy ...

I'd like to know if there's an elegant way to treat these constraint errors, giving a beautiful like "you can delete this object because it is associated to X"

How could I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

React in the before destroy callback:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :no_referenced_orders
  has_many :orders

  private

  def no_referenced_orders
    return if orders.empty?

    errors.add_to_base("This customer is referenced by order(s): #{orders.map(&:number).to_sentence}")
    false # If you return anything else, the callback will not stop the destroy from happening
  end
end
```

In the controller:

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    if @customer.destroy then
      redirect_to customers_url
    else
      render :action => :edit
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `add_to_base` is deprecated. (Last working version v2.3.8)
For Rails 3+, use `errors[:base] << "err_msg"` or `errors.add(:base, "err_msg")`