# cannot delete or update a parent row a foreign key constraint fails rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have received the following error when trying to delete a value in rails "**cannot delete or update a parent row a foreign key constraint fails rails**"

This is perfectly acceptable to me as I don't want the user to be able to delete the value if it's associated with another value. However, what is the best way to catch the exception and then notify 'alert' the user that this value cannot be deleted?

Thank You,

TW

Comment: @mattforni I will check out that post. For now I had just tried to put a `flash[:notice] = "Cannot be deleted"`, underneath `@value.destory` under `def destroy`in the controller. Then calling a flash notice in the view.

Comment: That's one way to do it.  It's probably not the recommended way, or most error prone handling, but everything is an iterative process.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to handle this gracefully.  If you'd like to do a check before the destroy I recommend you take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290710/rails-activerecord-pretty-errors-when-deleting-dependent-entities-with-foreign) as it shows a good example of using the `before_destroy` method and gives you control of the error you show.  However, you can also add a `rescue_from` and [capture the error in your controller](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
*********** Mysql Error:
"Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails."
```

This error message is usually raised by the database(mysql) and not rails(active record), and will usually be wrapped in an active record exception like `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`

Try the following to figure out which exception to catch:

```
begin
   <delete action expected to raise the above mentioned error>
rescue Exception => e
  logger.debug "#{e.class}"
end
```